# Catching reactively deleted select options in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a simple form within a template.  The form has a select.  The select options are tied to a collection. The form data is also tied to a collection.  If I change the form collection remotely my template updates.  If I change the collection supplying the select options the select updates.  But I want to be notified when the select options are changed remotely.  I have the options being generated within their own template.

I have the following in my Template.selOptions.rendered function:

```
this.autorun(function() {
    Blaze.getData();
    console.log('Options changed');
})
```

If I add an option remotely I get a console message.  If I delete a select option remotely, I don't get a message - even though the select changes.

I'm stumped and don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

If your options are tied to a collection, you can use [`observe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) or [`observeChanges`](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes):

```
Options.find(optionsQuery).observeChanges({

  added: function() {...},
  changed: function() {...},
  removed: function() {...},

});
```

Comment: It shouldn't have to be that difficult.  The autorun catches additions, so it should catch deletions as well.  Either I'm missing something obvious, or there's a bug in Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a template for options, then have a rendered callback - and for my problem - a destroyed callback.